# Building a simple Node.js scraper function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm tryign to build a very simple scraper function for nodeJS - just a function that I can pass a URL to, and it returns the scraped data as `var data`.

I'm completely new to Node.js and can't work out why the following isn't working:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

function scrape(url) {
    console.log("Scraping: " + url);
    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {

            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var html = cheerio.load(body);
            return html;
        });
}


var data = scrape('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

$ = data;
var logo = $('#hlogo a').text();
console.log(logo);
```

The above code should return `"Stack Overflow"` but obviously does not. When I run this in the console I get an error:

```
var logo = $('#hlogo a').text();
           ^
TypeError: Property '$' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

Any ideas why this isn't working for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` will be undefined, because `scrape` function does not return a value, additionaly it asynchronous.

You need change logic to something like this:

```
function scrape(url, oncomplete) {
    console.log("Scraping: " + url);
    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var html = cheerio.load(body);
        oncomplete(html);
    });
}


scrape('http://www.stackoverflow.com', function(data) { /* do work here*/ });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why asynchronous is bad here? I'd like to be able to throw multiple URLs at it and scrape them in unison (e.g. have 100 urls in an array, and use a `for loop` to iterate through them and call `scrape()` on each in parallel. Or am I not undertsanding asynchronisity?

Comment: Am I said async is bad? Since JS is one-threaded async requests is the only way to achieve "parallel" scraping. But your code don't take into account that it async. I showed you how logic should look.